# confused about 'OR AND' operator logic

Tags: javascript, logic, operators

How do these return different results? I mean, both have true and false conditions. Are the final results dependent on a line's last operator condition?

Thanks, guys. Really confused JavaScript noob here.

```
console.log (2 >= 1 && 3 <= 4 && 4 >= 5)
```

```
console.log (3 <= 2 || 3 >= 2)
```

Comment: Your first condition `(true && false && false)` is using **and** means all have to be true to return true in the second use used **or** `(false || true)`, which means any true will return true
Try to check how the operators behave

Comment: very clear! This made more sense than the tutorial I'm going through itself. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When using the && operator, if the first condition fails, no other comparisons are done